# Magento 2.1.6: Error filtering template: Unable to write file into directory

Tags: magento2.1.6

after install Magento 2.1.6 on Windows 10 XAMPP I got this error in the frontend homepage:

> Error filtering template: Unable to write file into directory
>   \C:/xampp/htdocs/Magento/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/m/b.
>   Access forbidden.

I google it but I did not find any answer how to fix it.

Comment: make sure you have write access to the `pub/media` folder.

Comment: @Marius I have the complete access to the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to solve this issue:
in **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php:226**
remove the 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR'

```
private function getRelativePath($result)
{
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getModule());
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getMiscPath());
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getFilePath());
return $result;
}
```

and:
**/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php:130**
replace DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to '/'

```
 private function join($path, $item)
    {
        return trim(
            $path . ($item ? '/' . ltrim($item, '/') : ''),
            '/'
        );
    }
```

PHP accepts both \ and / as valid path separators. So just use / in your code.

Comment: Hello @jitendra kumar, thank you very much for your answer. I also made the second change at line 130 and I am now able to view all the sample images in the frontend and in the backend thunmnail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR" issue in your path.

open vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php. Go to lie number 226 and remove the 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR'

```
private function getRelativePath($result)
{
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getModule());
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getMiscPath());
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getFilePath());
return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amitkumar solanki, I have removed the 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR' in line 231 but I still have the error in the homepage. Thanks

Comment: @Albydaz, Please clear cache and run php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.  I got same error and resolved it.

Comment: After removing the 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR' in line 231, clear all cache folders from var/cache and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy the error is still in the homepage:                                     
Error filtering template: Unable to write file into directory \C:/xampp/htdocs/Magento/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857\/m/b. Access forbidden.

Comment: Hello Albydaz, contact me on skype with  my skype id developer_amit_php, we will resolve it.

Comment: I started Magento this morning and the error was gone. I can see images in the frontpage now. Thank you for your help!