# Magento 2.1.6 Unable to write file into directory \D:/XAMPP/htdocs/magento/pub/media/catalog/product\cache

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.1.6

The error message appears every time I upload image on a product.

The complete message is:

> Unable to write file into directory \D:/XAMPP/htdocs/magento/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\914b1ba9268f8c1d0e58a8e7ce614488/s/o. Access forbidden.

The version of Magento I installed is 2.1.6, on XAMPP for Windows. The version of PHP installed in XAMPP is PHP 5.6.20.

I've tried:

- Editing `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php` as stated in this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170475/53491), that is, replacing all occurrences of `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` with `'/'` and editing `getRelativePath` function
- ...and this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170715/53491), that instructs to remove `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` in line 226
- `chmod -R 777 ./` on `/XAMPP/htdocs/magento/pub/media/catalog/product` with Bash, in case it has something to do with the permission

And nothing above has worked for me, except that the first option I tried give me a new error when I upload image on a product:

> The file "D:/XAMPP/htdocs/magento/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/s/o/test_image.png" doesn't exist or not a file

But when I check the file, it exists there!:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9212

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple way to solve this issue:
in **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php:226**
remove the 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR'

```
private function getRelativePath($result)
{
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getModule());
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getMiscPath());
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getFilePath());
return $result;
}
```

and:
**/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php:130**
replace DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to '/'

```
 private function join($path, $item)
    {
        return trim(
            $path . ($item ? '/' . ltrim($item, '/') : ''),
            '/'
        );
    }
```

PHP accepts both \ and / as valid path separators. So just use / in your code.